XSLT 1.0 to trace up inheritance tree of XML object
I am writing an XSLT to convert from an XML schema to python classes. The schema has deep inheritance trees going down seven to eight classes deep, and I need to write the output starting from the top and then working down to each child class. I would prefer doing this in XSLT 1.0 as the tool I am integrating with seems to be having problems with XSLT 2.0.
Schema:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog name="schema">

    <Root name="ChildClassA">
        <SuperType name="ParentClass"/>
    </Root>

    <Root name="ChildClassB">
        <SuperType name="ParentClass"/>
    </Root>

    <Root name="ParentClass">
        <SuperType name="GrandparentClass"/>
    </Root>

    <Root name="GrandparentClass">
    </Root>
             
</catalog>

Desired output:
class GrandparentClass():
    ""

class ParentClass(GrandparentClass):
    ""

class ChildClassA(ParentClass):
    ""

class ChildClassB(ParentClass):
    ""

My existing transform is able to sort the GrandparentClass as being defined first, but cannot figure out that ParentClass needs to be defined before ChildClass.
Is there 1) a way to use a recursive call-template name="supertype" to trace up the inheritance tree and 2) a way to check if the ParentClass has been written?

I don't fully understand the logic of your expected output. Still, it is easy to reconstruct the hierarchical tree using a key:
XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-parent" match="Root" use="SuperType/@name" />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <tree name="{@name}">
        <!-- select progenitors -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Root[not(SuperType)]"/>
    </tree>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Root">
    <item name="{@name}">
        <!-- select children -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('item-by-parent', @name)"/>
    </item>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tree name="schema">
  <item name="GrandparentClass">
    <item name="ParentClass">
      <item name="ChildClassA"/>
      <item name="ChildClassB"/>
    </item>
  </item>
</tree>

